# Entity Framework Eager Loading Multi Levels, Without String

Tags: entity-framework, nested, eager-loading

This is one way to do Eager Loading:

```
dim Q = from o in contex.Orders.Include("Items").Include("Items.Products")
```

I want to do that without using Strings.

With one level it's easy:

```
dim Q = from o in contex.Orders.Include(Function(x) x.Items)
```

But how do you do the include to include Items.Products?

Answer (score 2):

**EF5 Strings**

New to EF5 are named include parameters.

**Muliple include levels**

You can include multiple child level eager fetches using the following syntax

var orders = db.Orders.Include(a => a.Items.Select(c => c.Products));

Comment: It only allows me to use a path in the Include function, am I missing something?